# Append a new object to a JSON Array only if an attribute on object NOT exists. DynamoDB using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to append a new object to an object list in DynamoDB.
Example schema:

```
{
   "ActivityId" : "1",
   "name" : "testName",
   "package" : [
     {
        "objectId" : "111",
        "objname" : "name1",
        "objvalue" : "1",
        "items" : [],
     },
     {
        "objectId" : "222",
        "objname" : "name2",
        "objvalue" : "2",
        "items" : [],
     }
   ]

}
```

For example i need to add a new package only if objectId NOT exists in package list.
Adding the obj below the system will return an error because the objectId is already present in the package list.
At this time i can to append this example item but it should not.

How can i do this?? thanks guys.

```
{
      "objectId" : "111",
      "objname" : "name3",
      "objvalue" : "3",
      "items" : []
},
```

This is my code:

```
    const packageItem = {
        "objectId" : "111",
        "objname" : "obj3",
        "objvalue" : "3",
        "items" : []
    }

    const params = {
        TableName: dynamodbTableName,
        Key: {
            "ActivityId" : req.params.ActivityId
        },
        Item: {

        },
        ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW",
        UpdateExpression: 'set #package = list_append(#package, :packageItem)',

        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            '#package' : 'package',
            '#menu_id' : 'menu_id'
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':packageItem' : [packageItem],
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common mistake that can cause users anguish. When you use a List, you must know the position of the object on the list to do a condition check on it. However, if you restructure your list to a Map, then you can easily achieve your use-case:

```
{
   "ActivityId" : "1",
   "name" : "testName",
   "package" : {
   "111":
     {
        "objectId" : "111",
        "objname" : "name1",
        "objvalue" : "1",
        "items" : [],
     },
   "222":
     {
        "objectId" : "222",
        "objname" : "name2",
        "objvalue" : "2",
        "items" : [],
     }
   }

}
```

`ConditionExression="not_exists(package.111)`

I have not tested this as I'm on a phone, but that should give you more control of what you want to do.